# Exception that is handled is still thrown?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

My code:

```
public void CPUStats()
{
    var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", 
                                                                     "_Total");
    var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
    ramCounter.NextValue();
    cpuCounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    string cpusage = cpuCounter.NextValue().ToString();
    string ramusage = ramCounter.NextValue().ToString();

    //Occurs here v
    try
    {
        //exception thrown here v
        cpuLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => cpuLabel.Text = "CPU: " + 
                                   cpusage.Remove(cpusage.IndexOf('.')) + "%"));
    }
    catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        cpuLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => cpuLabel.Text = "CPU: " + 
                                                                 cpusage + "%"));
    }

    ramLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => ramLabel.Text = "Free RAM: " + 
                                                             ramusage + "mb"));
}
```

At times my application will stop at the cpuLabel invoke and throw an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" when it was handled and fixed in my code. I tried increasing the timer that activates the thread that activates CPUStats(), but to no avail.

Why would this happen?

Comment: in the debugger or in the release build?

Comment: Is the line in `catch` block generate exception?

Comment: Attach a debugger - with break on exceptions - and step through.

Comment: This isn't the best approach to the problem. Don't use a try/catch to replace logical control elements. You should check to see if `cpusage` contains a `.` and then take the appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Sorry, I should read your code more carefully. Your `try-catch` wrapped the delegate invocation which **may not in the current context of thread**. I think what you want to do should be:

```
public void CPUStats() {
    var cpuCounter= .. 

    ... 

    MethodInvoker m=() => {
        try {
            cpuLabel.Text="CPU: "+cpusage.Remove(cpusage.IndexOf('.'))+"%";
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
            cpuLabel.Text="CPU: "+cpusage+"%";
        }
    };

    cpuLabel.Invoke(m);

    ... 
}
```

Have a look of [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) and also [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx).

Again, avoid `try-catch` if there's a better way to check for possible errors.

---

@competent_tech's answer is good, but I'd like to add a little bit.

There are some cases that a `try-catch` block would still throw:

1. You did not catch the exact exception it thrown
2. The handler rethrows the original exception
3. The handler causes another exception

<del>In your case, it hits the `catch` block and did not rethrow the original one, that is, it met the third circumstance: the handler causes another exception.</del>

If you can address the problem causes the exception and avoid it , then don't design it in this way.

Mr. Lippert wrote a good article about the exceptions, you might want to have a look at:

http://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: How could that handler throw an exception?

Comment: `cpuLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => cpuLabel.Text = "CPU: " +                                                               cpusage + "%"));` Doesn't throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is being caused by this code:

```
cpusage.Remove(cpusage.IndexOf('.')
```

You need to ensure that cpusage has length and contains a '.' before attempting to call .Remove.

You can prove this by running a simple app test:

```
        var cpuusage = "0";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cpuusage.Remove(cpuusage.IndexOf('.')));
```

This will throw the ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception.

If you modify the code to be:

```
        var cpuusageforlabel = "CPU: ";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpuusage)) {
            var index = cpuusage.IndexOf('.');
            if (index != -1) {
                cpuusageforlabel += cpuusage.Remove(index);
            } else {
                cpuusageforlabel += cpuusage;
            }
        } else {
            cpuusageforlabel += "0";
        }
        cpuusageforlabel += "%";

   cpuLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => cpuLabel.Text = cpuusageforlabel));
```

You address the exception and won't have to catch the argument out of range exception.

Comment: You haven't explained at all why `catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)` doesn't catch.  The real issue, the OP already knew that AOORE was being thrown.  That's why he wrote the catch.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry, I did not get that at all from the description of the issue or the code. The OP indicated explictly where the exception was being thrown and I thought that the issue was the OP didn't understand why it was still being thrown even though there was a catch statement (i.e. it's not being thrown out of the catch statement).

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that `cpusage` is null or empty or without **.**. So when you get exception and try to use same variable again, you get the second exception.

Check `cpusage` before using it and don't use `catch` the way you are using.